# ¿Cómo servir archivos estaticos en Nodejs con express y sails?

Tags: nodejs, express, sailsjs

Estoy cargando archivos con Angular a un servidor **Node que usa Sailsjs**, luego de cargar los archivos quiero **obtener una ruta para mostrarlos en el frontend**.

Incluyo express en el archivo http de sails pasando la ruta donde tengo los archivos estaticos y luego subo el servidor normalmente, el problema está en que cuando quiero acceder a los archivos, si por ejemplo pongo http://localhost:1337/assets/videos/imagen.jpg, **el servidor se queda cargando y nunca responde**.

Código de http.js

```
var express=require('express');
var appi = express();
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: [
      'expressEstatico',
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
    expressEstatico:function(app){
       console.log(appi);
       appi.use(express.static('assets/videos'));
    }
  },
};
```

Como puedo configurar el archivo http para poder servir datos estáticos?

Comment: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ponerlo en tu `.sailsrc`, asi es como lo tengo para servir los ficheros desde assets, sails deberia leer estos ficheros y automaticamente servir la carpeta, aqui deberia servir la carpeta `assets`

### .sailsrc

```
{
  "paths": {
    "public": "assets"
  }
}
```

Comment: Al agregarlo en el .sailssrc debería eliminar la configuración que hay en el http.js?, ya lo puse y continuo con este error https://ibb.co/k0mFgv